# Issue building WSO2 Governance registry source code

Tags: wso2

I have been trying to build the WSO2 Governance registry from the source code checked out from '_http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/4.0.5/products/greg/4.5.3' as mentioned in the site.

I am getting the following error while running the pom.xml

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building WSO2 Governance Registry Source 4.5.3
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- incremental-build-plugin:1.3:incremental-build (default) @ wso2greg-src ---
[INFO] Verifying module descriptor ...
[INFO] Verifying parent modules...
[INFO] Verifying resources...
[INFO] Resources directory does not exist : H:\WorkSpace_1\WSO2\modules\source\src\main\resources
[INFO] Verifying sources...
[INFO] No sources to check ...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.1:run (clean-checkout) @ wso2greg-src ---
[INFO] Executing tasks
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-svn-revision-number-plugin:1.1:revision (default) @ wso2greg-src ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gmaven-plugin:1.0-rc-5:execute (default) @ wso2greg-src ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.1.1:exec (default) @ wso2greg-src ---
[INFO] svn: E160013: '/repos/wso2/!svn/rvr/170534/branches/solutions/governance/4.5.3' **path not found**
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.125s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Apr 17 19:37:22 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/12M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1.1:exec (default) on project wso2greg-src: Result of cmd.exe /X /C "svn co -r170329 _https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/branches/solutions/governance/4.5.3 checkout" execution is: '1'. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] _http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I have tried hitting the mentioned repository location '_https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/branches/solutions/governance/4.5.3' manually but a repository with version number **4.5.3 does not exist.**

Can anybody suggest an alternative location if you know of, or any other way to build it successfully.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to build the source?..It is bit difficult for a newbie..
If you really need it,You have to take checkout from here[1]
and need to build

- dependencies
- service stubs
- components
- features
- product
  Before that you need to build the orbit[2] and kernel[3] of the same version

[1]https://svn.wso2.com/wso2/custom/projects/projects/carbon/4.0.0/platform/tags/4.0.5/
[2]https://svn.wso2.com/wso2/custom/projects/projects/carbon/4.0.0/orbit/tags/4.0.5/
[3]https://svn.wso2.com/wso2/custom/projects/projects/carbon/4.0.0/kernel/tags/4.0.5/

Comment: Hi Ratha.. Thanks for your reply. I need to customize the governance registry to suit the needs of my company. What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Then try build as pointed in my previous answer..order is, orbit then kernel finally platform..Each has submodules..when you face build issue..you can check the modules and overcome..Do maven online build..#mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true

Comment: Hi Ratha, I am tying to check out from the specified location,but it requires credetials to connect.

Comment: I tried using http links. It is still asking for authorization. I registered into the site and tried using those credentials but it tells me that I dont have th required privileges. I tried browsing the site for some help. I found this link http://wso2.org/node/608/print but none of the links related to governance repository seem to work...    Please help me. I am running out of time.