# Uable to build WSO2 API Mngt 4.0.7

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

```
When i am trying to build wso2 api mgnt i got this error: Please help me
```

mvn clean install

```
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE

    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    [INFO] Total time: 15:22.482s

    [INFO] Finished at: Wed Apr 24 15:02:05 IST 2013

    [INFO] Final Memory: 19M/490M

    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------


[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wso2.maven:carbon-p2-plugin:1.5:p2-profile-gen
```

(3-p2-profile-generation) on project am-p2-profile: P2 publisher return code was 13 -> [

Comment: You can check [this post][1] on how to build a carbon product 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062862/issue-building-wso2-governance-registry-source-code

Answer (score 0):

First you have to build orbit then kernal and after that the platform. Have you done that order. If you get the same error can you paste full error log.

Thanks !